# Rewrite a CSV : from a ; x to y kg ; to a ;x ; y

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I've got a CSV that looks like:

```
High_Female;18 to 28 cm;25 to 30 cm;52 to 62 cm
Weight_Male;8 to 10 Kg;4 to 6 Kg;28 to 32 Kg
```

I convert it to an array with these function generally:

```
def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):
    csv_data = []
    for line in content.split('\n'):
        # strips spaces also
        csv_data.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(delimiter )])
    return csv_data
```

I would like to be able to turn things into:

```
High Female Max ; 28 ; 30; 62
High female Min ; 18 ; 25 ; 52
Weight Min ; 8 ; 4 ; 28
Weight Max ; 10 ; 6 ; 32
```

I'll just need to transform the:

```
x to y unit
```

into a couple [x,y] and take the min and max and put them into an array.

1. replace "unit" with ""    `list.replace("unit","")`
2. replace "to" with ""
3. Then  ? Convert a string into a list with `.split`

Or is there something more efficient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple conversion, using regular expressions:

```
>>> s
'High_Female;18 to 28 cm;25 to 30 cm;52 to 62 cm'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+) to (\d+)', s)
[('18', '28'), ('25', '30'), ('52', '62')]
```

You can then find the min/max for your application. Plugging it into your function:

```
import csv

def parse_csv(filename, delimiter=',')
    results = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delimiter)
        for row in reader:
            label = row[0].replace('_', ' ')
            mins = []
            maxes = []
            for line in row[1:]:
                x,y = re.findall(r'(\d+) to (\d+)', line)
                mins.append(int(x))
                maxes.append(int(y))
            mins.sort()
            maxes.sort()
            results['{} Min:'.format(label)] = ';'.join(mins)
            results['{} Max:'.format(label)] = ';'.join(maxes)
    return results

print(parse_csv('somefile.txt', ';'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree it would be easiest to extract the numbers with a regular expression, but then do the rest of formatting and processing like this:

```
import csv
import re

content = [
    "High_Female;18 to 28 cm;25 to 30 cm;52 to 62 cm",
    "Weight_Male;8 to 10 Kg;4 to 6 Kg;28 to 32 Kg",
]

for row in csv.reader(content, delimiter=';'):
    values = []
    for pair in row[1:]:
        values.append(map(int, re.findall(r'(\d+) to (\d+)', pair)[0]))
    highs = [max(v) for v in values]
    lows = [min(v) for v in values]
    label = row[0].replace('_', ' ')
    print('{} max ; {}'.format(label, ' ; '.join(str(high) for high in highs)))
    print('{} min ; {}'.format(label, ' ; '.join(str(low) for low in lows)))
```

Output:

```
High Female max ; 28 ; 30 ; 62
High Female min ; 18 ; 25 ; 52
Weight Male max ; 10 ; 6 ; 32
Weight Male min ; 8 ; 4 ; 28
```

Comment: Thanks it works like this. My version was more archaic but worked also :) concerning the max/min formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
in_str = "18 to 28 cm"
x,y = [int(s) for s in in_str.split() if s.isdigit()]
print x, y
```

Of you could use regex...